# Need to convert SQL query to Linq contains "group by having distinct count" clause

Tags: linq, group-by

I need to convert oracle SQL query to linq query,  which contains "group by having distinct count" clause.

Below is the query:

```
select po.id from Purchaseorder po 
inner join POlineitem poline 
on poline.purchaseorderid=po.id   
where po.id in(236604,240480,240972,242622,242929,243293,244535)         
group by po.id having count(distinct poline.orderstatus)=1
```

Here `Purchaseorder` is the parent table which might have multiple lines in  `POlineitem` table. `poline.orderstatus` can have specific status values like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
int[] objlist={236604,240480,240972,242622,242929,243293,244535};

from a in Contex.Purchaseorder.where(x=>objlist.Contain(x.id))
join b in Contex.POlineitem.Distinct(x=>x.orderstatus) on a.id equals b.purchaseorderid
group item by a.id into groupedItems
let count = groupedItems.Count()
where count==1
select item.key
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the query portion Contex.POlineitem.Distinct(x=>x.orderstatus) does not work.

Comment: Sure, could you please check why .Distinct(x=>x.orderstatus) is not working and what should be the correct way to write this logic

Comment: Actually I cant vote until my reputation doesn't reach to 15